# book/tutorial on using rpy2 in python for kriging?

Tags: python, r, kriging, references

I am proficient in Python, but have no knowledge of R. Can you suggest a good tutorial in using **rpy2** or any other R library to perform **Block/Cokriging "Kriging"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if your are proficient in Python, you can manage the rpy2 part ([there are examples here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/index.html)), but you need more a book on spatial statistics in R. That would probably be [Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R](http://www.asdar-book.org/). Section 8.5 is about spatial predictions. The book is available online through library subscription, but the code from the chapter is [freely available](http://www.asdar-book.org/book/geos_mod.R) (have a look at chunk 15 and following). [gstat's vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/vignettes/gstat.pdf) also provide step by step tutorial.

While I don't work with rpy2 a lot, I generally find it easier to work the R code in R, and once it's OK, run it through python.

Comment: The example provided is for rpy, not rpy2.

Comment: Hi! Etiennebr, thanks for suggesting a good book for geostatistics with R. I was just wondering about _"to work the R code in R, and once it's OK, run it through python."_ How is the R code run in Python?

Comment: That's where rpy2 comes in. Have a look at the rpy2 documentation. It's a module you load in python that allows you to interact with R from python.